# problem with dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

Im trying out some sample code from a dojo tutorial. I have

```
    <button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" id="helloButton">
    Test
    <script type="dojo/method" event="onClick">
        dojo.xhrGet({
            url: 'response.txt',
            load: testCallback,
            error: testError
        });
        alert("getting thru");
    </script>   
</button>
```

When I click my button, I get my error callback is run, but i cant figure out why.

This is testCallback

```
  function testCallback(data, ioArgs)
  {
    alert(data);
  }
```

and I have a file called response.txt that is in the same folder as my index.html. I am really puzzled!

Any suggestions??

Thanks

Ying

Comment: Code looks fine.  Do you have firebug installed?  If not, install it and watch the XHR GET request your code block is making to see the actual URL it's trying to view.  Maybe a permissions problem on response.txt?

Comment: installing firebug assumes you are running firefox BTW.

Comment: Not so much anymore: http://getfirebug.com/lite.html

Comment: True that TML.  Thanks I always forget about lite.

Comment: So Ive installed firebug, but it doesn't "catch" the error. I still see the error which is say 127.0.0.1:8000 says : (then followed by my error message. I checked that the port is indeed open by doing netstat, and it says the port status is listen. i did chmod 777 on my response.txt file. still the same error. not sure how to work firebug to give me better errors!

Comment: So, the XHR call in firebug is going to http://127.0.0.1:8000/response.txt and you can bring up that URL in a browser?  Does the error message inside of your testError function have anything?

Answer (score 1):

I rebooted the computer and everything seemed to work. I could not recreate the error, luckily. To recap:

1) set permissions on response.txt 
2) make sure port 8000 is open using netstat -an

Thanks for all that chipped in!